# Android - is <uses-feature> element necessary?

Tags: android

Given an Android app that does NOT require any of the features that need to be declared in the

```
<uses-feature>
```

element of the manifest, is it best to omit this element entirely or include it with no attributes? Will either option have any different effects on your apps visibility/availability in the market?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From 's [docs](http://developer.android.com/intl/zh-TW/guide/topics/manifest/uses-feature-element.html)

> Declaring a  element is
>   informational only, meaning that the
>   Android system itself does not check
>   for matching feature support on the
>   device before installing an
>   application. However, note that other
>   services (such as Android Market) or
>   applications may check your
>   application's 
>   declarations as part of handling or
>   interacting with your application. For
>   this reason, it's very important that
>   you declare all of the features (from
>   the list below) that your application
>   uses.

If you are not using any feature that needs to have a `<uses-feature>` in the manifest, just remove the whole tag.